# GENIE Generator is unable to link to GSL library (undefined reference to `gsl_spline2d_*')

Tags: compiling, shared-library

I am trying to install GENIE Generator in Ubuntu 18.04 which depends on

Installing Prerequisites:

- ROOT(version 6.14.00)
- GNU Scientific Library (GSL)
- PYTHIA6
- LHAPDF5 or LHAPDF6
- log4cpp
- libxml2

I have installed PYTHIA6, LHAPDF6, log4cpp, libxml2, GSL as well as ROOT with GSL. I can run following test code (with GSL function) using both g++ as well as root.

```
#include<iostream>
#include "gsl/gsl_sf_bessel.h"
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    double x = 15.0;
    double y = gsl_sf_bessel_J0 (x);
    cout<<x<<"\t"<<y<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I use this command to run this test file.

```
g++ hello.cc -o hello $(gsl-config --cflags --libs)
./hello
```

This indicate that GSL is properly installed in system. I have exported path in .bashrc file also.

```
# For ROOT

#export ROOTSYS=/home/anil/Products/root

export ROOTSYS=/home/anil/Products/root_v6.14.00-build

export PATH=$ROOTSYS/bin:$PATH

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ROOTSYS/lib/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH

#Pythia 8
export PYTHIA8=/home/anil/Products/pythia8235
export PYTHIA8DATA=$PYTHIA8/share/Pythia8/xmldoc
export PATH=$PYTHIA8/bin:$PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$PYTHIA8/lib

#Pythia 6
export PYTHIA6=/home/anil/Products/pythia6428
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$PYTHIA6428/lib

#GSL-2.5
export GSLHOME=/home/anil/Products/gsl25
export GSL_INC=$GSLHOME/include
export GSL_LIB=$GSLHOME/lib
export PATH=$GSLHOME/bin:$PATH
#export LIBRARY_PATH=$LIBRARY_PATH:$GSLHOME/lib
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$GSLHOME/lib


#CLHEP-2.4.0.4
export CLHEP_BASE_DIR=/home/anil/Products/CLHEP/clhep2404
export PATH=$CLHEP_BASE_DIR/bin:$PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$CLHEP_BASE_DIR/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH

#GEANT4
export G4INSTALL=/home/anil/Products/GEANT4/geant4.10.04.p02-install/share/Geant4-10.4.2/geant4make
export G4WORKDIR=/home/anil/G4WORK
source $G4INSTALL/geant4make.sh
source /home/anil/Products/GEANT4/geant4.10.04.p02-install/bin/geant4.sh
```

Now when I am running the compilation of GENIE Generator and it shows error.

```
cd ~/Products
mkdir GENIE
cd GENIE
git clone https://github.com/GENIE-MC/Generator.git
cd Generator
export GENIE=$(pwd)

./configure --prefix=/home/anil/Products/GENIE/genie --disable-profiler --disable-validation-tools --disable-cernlib --enable-lhapdf6 --enable-flux-drivers --enable-geom-drivers --disable-doxygen --enable-test --enable-mueloss --enable-dylibversion --enable-t2k --enable-fnal --enable-atmo --enable-nucleon-decay --disable-masterclass --disable-debug --with-optimiz-level=O2 --with-pythia6-lib=/home/anil/Products/pythia6428/libPythia6.so --with-lhapdf6-inc=/home/anil/Products/LHAPDF/lhapdf621/include --with-lhapdf6-lib=/home/anil/Products/LHAPDF/lhapdf621/lib --with-libxml2-inc=/home/anil/Products/LIBXML2/libxml2/include/libxml2 --with-libxml2-lib=/home/anil/Products/LIBXML2/libxml2/lib --with-log4cpp-inc=/home/anil/Products/LOG4CPP/log4cpp/include --with-log4cpp-lib=/home/anil/Products/LOG4CPP/log4cpp/lib

********************************************************************************************************
********************************************************************************************************
**                                                                                                    **
**   .oooooo.    oooooooooooo ooooo      ooo ooooo oooooooooooo                                       **
**  d8P'  `Y8b   `888'     `8 `888b.     `8' `888' `888'     `8      NEUTRINO MONTE CARLO GENERATOR   **
** 888            888          8 `88b.    8   888   888                                               **
** 888            888oooo8     8   `88b.  8   888   888oooo8              Version 999.999.999         **
** 888     ooooo  888    "     8     `88b.8   888   888    "                                          **
** `88.    .88'   888       o  8       `888   888   888       o         http://www.genie-mc.org       **
**  `Y8bood8P'   o888ooooood8 o8o        `8  o888o o888ooooood8                                       **
**                                                                                                    **
** (c) 2003-2018 GENIE Collaboration                                                                  **
**                                                                                                    **
********************************************************************************************************
********************************************************************************************************
/home/anil/Products/GENIE/Generator/configure

The $PYTHIA6 env var is defined. I will pick that and set --with-pythia6-lib=/home/anil/Products/pythia6428

Your input configuration options were: --prefix=/home/anil/Products/GENIE/genie --disable-profiler --disable-validation-tools --disable-cernlib --enable-lhapdf6 --enable-flux-drivers --enable-geom-drivers --disable-doxygen --enable-test --enable-mueloss --enable-dylibversion --enable-t2k --enable-fnal --enable-atmo --enable-nucleon-decay --disable-masterclass --disable-debug --with-optimiz-level=O2 --with-pythia6-lib=/home/anil/Products/pythia6428/libPythia6.so --with-lhapdf6-inc=/home/anil/Products/LHAPDF/lhapdf621/include --with-lhapdf6-lib=/home/anil/Products/LHAPDF/lhapdf621/lib --with-libxml2-inc=/home/anil/Products/LIBXML2/libxml2/include/libxml2 --with-libxml2-lib=/home/anil/Products/LIBXML2/libxml2/lib --with-log4cpp-inc=/home/anil/Products/LOG4CPP/log4cpp/include --with-log4cpp-lib=/home/anil/Products/LOG4CPP/log4cpp/lib

The /home/anil/Products/GENIE/Generator/src/make/Make.config file has been succesfully generated! 
The following config options were set: 
  GENIE_INSTALLATION_PATH=/home/anil/Products/GENIE/genie
  GOPT_ENABLE_LHAPDF5=NO
  GOPT_ENABLE_LHAPDF6=YES
  GOPT_ENABLE_T2K=YES
  GOPT_ENABLE_FNAL=YES
  GOPT_ENABLE_ATMO=YES
  GOPT_ENABLE_NUCLEON_DECAY=YES
  GOPT_ENABLE_NNBAR_OSCILLATION=NO
  GOPT_ENABLE_BOOSTED_DARK_MATTER=NO
  GOPT_ENABLE_FLUX_DRIVERS=YES
  GOPT_ENABLE_GEOM_DRIVERS=YES
  GOPT_ENABLE_MASTERCLASS=NO
  GOPT_ENABLE_TEST=YES
  GOPT_ENABLE_PROFILER=NO
  GOPT_ENABLE_DOXYGEN_DOC=NO
  GOPT_ENABLE_DYLIBVERSION=YES
  GOPT_ENABLE_LOW_LEVEL_MESG=NO
  GOPT_WITH_COMPILER=gcc
  GOPT_WITH_CXX_DEBUG_FLAG=
  GOPT_WITH_CXX_OPTIMIZ_FLAG=-O2
  GOPT_WITH_PROFILER_LIB=
  GOPT_WITH_DOXYGEN_PATH=
  GOPT_WITH_PYTHIA6_LIB=/home/anil/Products/pythia6428
  GOPT_WITH_LHAPDF5_LIB=
  GOPT_WITH_LHAPDF5_INC=
  GOPT_WITH_LHAPDF6_LIB=/home/anil/Products/LHAPDF/lhapdf621/lib
  GOPT_WITH_LHAPDF6_INC=/home/anil/Products/LHAPDF/lhapdf621/include
  GOPT_WITH_LIBXML2_INC=/home/anil/Products/LIBXML2/libxml2/include/libxml2
  GOPT_WITH_LIBXML2_LIB=/home/anil/Products/LIBXML2/libxml2/lib
  GOPT_WITH_LOG4CPP_INC=/home/anil/Products/LOG4CPP/log4cpp/include
  GOPT_WITH_LOG4CPP_LIB=/home/anil/Products/LOG4CPP/log4cpp/lib

*** To continue building GENIE type: make

make
```

After this it shows the following error.

```
.
.
.
g++ -c  -W -Wall -fPIC -Wshadow -pthread -std=c++11 -m64 -I/home/anil/Products/root_v6.14.00-build/include  -O2    -I/home/anil/Products/LIBXML2/libxml2/include/libxml2  -I/home/anil/Products/LOG4CPP/log4cpp/include -I/home/anil/Products/root_v6.14.00-build/include -I/home/anil/Products/GENIE/Generator/src/  _ROOT_DICT_TlGeo.cc
[package: Tools/Geometry] Generating shared library ..dictionary=._ROOT_DICT_TlGeo
g++ -shared  GeomVolSelectorFiducial.o GeomVolSelectorI.o GeoUtils.o ROOTGeomAnalyzer.o PointGeomAnalyzer.o PathSegmentList.o GeomVolSelectorRockBox.o GeomVolSelectorBasic.o FidShape.o _ROOT_DICT_TlGeo.o  -o /home/anil/Products/GENIE/Generator/lib/libGTlGeo-999.999.999.so
[ ! -f libGTlGeo_rdict.pcm ] || cp libGTlGeo_rdict.pcm /home/anil/Products/GENIE/Generator/lib
[ ! -f libGTlGeo.rootmap ] || cp libGTlGeo.rootmap /home/anil/Products/GENIE/Generator/lib
[package: Tools/Geometry] Creating symbolic link to shared library ...
ln -sf libGTlGeo-999.999.999.so /home/anil/Products/GENIE/Generator/lib/libGTlGeo.so
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/anil/Products/GENIE/Generator/src/Tools/Geometry'

** Masterclass was not enabled. Skipping...

** Building GENIE applications...
cd /home/anil/Products/GENIE/Generator/src/Apps && \
make all && \
cd /home/anil/Products/GENIE/Generator
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/anil/Products/GENIE/Generator/src/Apps'
g++  -W -Wall -fPIC -Wshadow -pthread -std=c++11 -m64 -I/home/anil/Products/root_v6.14.00-build/include  -O2   -MMD -MP -c  -I/home/anil/Products/LIBXML2/libxml2/include/libxml2  -I/home/anil/Products/LOG4CPP/log4cpp/include -I/home/anil/Products/root_v6.14.00-build/include  -I/home/anil/Products/LHAPDF/lhapdf621/include -I/home/anil/Products/gsl25/include -I/home/anil/Products/GENIE/Generator/src/  gEvGen.cxx -o gEvGen.o
** Building gevgen
g++ -g -Wl,--no-as-needed -Wl,--no-undefined gEvGen.o  -L/home/anil/Products/root_v6.14.00-build/lib -lGui -lCore -lImt -lRIO -lNet -lHist -lGraf -lGraf3d -lGpad -lROOTDataFrame -lROOTVecOps -lTree -lTreePlayer -lRint -lPostscript -lMatrix -lPhysics -lMathCore -lThread -lMultiProc -pthread -lm -ldl -rdynamic -lMinuit -lGeom -lEG -lEGPythia6 -lGenVector -L/home/anil/Products/pythia6428 -lPythia6    -L/home/anil/Products/LHAPDF/lhapdf621/lib -lLHAPDF  -L/home/anil/Products/LIBXML2/libxml2/lib -lxml2 -L/home/anil/Products/LOG4CPP/log4cpp/lib -llog4cpp -L/home/anil/Products/gsl25/lib -lgsl -lgslcblas -lm  -lnsl  -L/home/anil/Products/GENIE/Generator/lib -lGFwMsg -lGFwReg -lGFwAlg -lGFwInt -lGFwGHEP -lGFwNum -lGFwUtl -lGFwParDat -lGFwEG -lGFwNtp -lGPhXSIg -lGPhPDF -lGPhNuclSt -lGPhCmn -lGPhDcy -lGPhHadTransp -lGPhHadnz -lGPhDeEx -lGPhAMNGXS -lGPhAMNGEG -lGPhChmXS -lGPhCohXS -lGPhCohEG -lGPhDISXS -lGPhDISEG -lGPhDfrcXS -lGPhDfrcEG -lGPhGlwResXS -lGPhGlwResEG -lGPhIBDXS -lGPhIBDEG -lGPhMNucXS -lGPhMNucEG -lGPhMEL -lGPhNuElXS -lGPhNuElEG -lGPhQELXS -lGPhQELEG -lGPhResXS -lGPhResEG -lGPhStrXS -lGPhStrEG -lGPhNDcy -lGTlGeo -lGTlFlx -o /home/anil/Products/GENIE/Generator/bin/gevgen
/home/anil/Products/GENIE/Generator/lib/libGFwNum.so: undefined reference to `gsl_spline2d_eval_deriv_y'
/home/anil/Products/GENIE/Generator/lib/libGFwNum.so: undefined reference to `gsl_spline2d_init'
/home/anil/Products/GENIE/Generator/lib/libGFwNum.so: undefined reference to `gsl_spline2d_eval_deriv_yy'
/home/anil/Products/GENIE/Generator/lib/libGFwNum.so: undefined reference to `gsl_interp_accel_alloc'
/home/anil/Products/GENIE/Generator/lib/libGFwNum.so: undefined reference to `gsl_spline2d_eval_deriv_x'
/home/anil/Products/GENIE/Generator/lib/libGFwNum.so: undefined reference to `gsl_interp2d_bilinear'
/home/anil/Products/GENIE/Generator/lib/libGFwNum.so: undefined reference to `gsl_spline2d_eval'
/home/anil/Products/GENIE/Generator/lib/libGFwNum.so: undefined reference to `gsl_spline2d_alloc'
/home/anil/Products/GENIE/Generator/lib/libGFwNum.so: undefined reference to `gsl_spline2d_eval_deriv_xy'
/home/anil/Products/GENIE/Generator/lib/libGFwNum.so: undefined reference to `gsl_spline2d_eval_deriv_xx'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:90: recipe for target '/home/anil/Products/GENIE/Generator/bin/gevgen' failed
make[1]: *** [/home/anil/Products/GENIE/Generator/bin/gevgen] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/anil/Products/GENIE/Generator/src/Apps'
Makefile:243: recipe for target 'apps' failed
make: *** [apps] Error 2
```

The *libgsl.a* file can be found in the following directories which is what we expect:

```
anil@anilpc:~/Products/GENIE/Generator$ locate libgsl.a
/home/anil/Products/gsl-2.5/.libs/libgsl.a
/home/anil/Products/gsl25/lib/libgsl.a
/home/anil/Products/root_v6.14.00-build/GSL-prefix/src/GSL-build/.libs/libgsl.a
/home/anil/Products/root_v6.14.00-build/lib/libgsl.a

anil@anilpc:~$ gsl-config --cflags --libs
-I/home/anil/Products/gsl25/include
-L/home/anil/Products/gsl25/lib -lgsl -lgslcblas -lm
```

Since the gsl-config shows location of library. It is clear that libgsl in installed properly (compiled mannually using source code) and the example C++ program can use the same functions without any error. But somehow the GENIE compilation is unable to use gsl library and show undefined functions.

It will be helpful if someone can give a clue what could be possibly wrong.

Comment: In the end, I have shown the output of gsl-config --cflags --libs which shows that the libgsl package is installed (manually compiled from source file) and the library is functioning properly. I am not sure why only during this compilation, the makefile is unable to use gsl whereas the same functions are working in normal C++ codes?

Answer (score 0):

It's probably too late for OP, but for anyone coming across this in the future, I found a workaround(?) for this.

There is a line in the Makefile for gevgen, in the `GENIE/Generator/src/Apps/` directory, which looks up the necessary libraries and their dependencies during compilation. It was returning `-L/path/to/ROOT/libs -lgsl`, for some reason trying to link against the gsl library in the ROOT libs directory, rather than the GSL directory. Perhaps if ROOT is built by the `lamp` script, such a dynamic library exists, but in my case (linking against an externally built ROOT) I was only able to find a static `libgsl.a` file. 
On the other hand a dynamic `libgsl.so` file was present at `GENIE/GENIESupport/gsl/lib/libgsl.so`, so i made a softlink to this file in the `ROOT/libs` directory, and thereafter the build completed without further problems.

Comment: I believe there was a similar problem in my case where I have installed root prerequisites (optional) which have libgsl0-dev package in the list. Since I was already using root before this complete installation of genie and I have installed these prerequisites which means the gsl ( older version) was already in the root directory (linux root). The GENIE installation was using those internal libraries instead of manually installed gsl. So I removed the old gsl library and deleted every possible gsl lib file in root directory. Then, I compiled and it worked. Hence, I suggest skipping libgsl0.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can point to the current GSL install find it:

```
locate libgsl | fgrep .so
```